# Can't limit access to shared calendar through impersonation using EWS

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

We're using EWS to integrate our CRM with Exchange Online 2010SP2. One of the tasks: provide one calendar for Sales persons with the next rule: every Sales can see all appointments in Scheduler, but can open and see details (body) only his/her own appointment. Appointment are being placed by CRM in response of certain business events. We tried to use impersonate and Sensitivity.Private property. Appointment is being placed with impersonated user name, but it can't be opened by that user neither through OWA nor via Outlook. So it's placed as private appointment of 'master' user (user who created shared calendar and his credentials is used for service connection), he can open it in Outlook or OWA. EWSEditor shows appointment's LastModifiedUser - correct impersonated username (not master's). In Fiddler we can see 'success' Response on appointment placement request (under impersonated user). In OutlookSpy, we can see that appointments  PR_SENDER_NAME_W, PR_SENT_REPRESENTING_NAME_W properties shows 'master's' username. We stuck.

Impersonated user has 'owner' rights upon that shared calendar.

If Impersonating doesn't resolve this issue, can Delegate technique do that?

Thanks in advance for any help.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ExchangeService services = new 
    ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP2);

    services.Credentials = new WebCredentials("master@exchserver.com", 
        "MasterPwd");
    services.Url = new Uri("https://someserver.com/ews/exchange.asmx");

    FolderId rfRootFolderid = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar);
    FolderView fvFolderView = new FolderView(100);

    DateTime startDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
    DateTime endDate;

    string SalesCalendarId = "AAMkADVlMGVjZWVkLT....AADo8XAAA=";

    CalendarFolder folder = CalendarFolder.Bind(services, new 
    FolderId(SalesCalendarId));

    TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(10, 00, 0);
    startDate = startDate.Date + ts;
    endDate = startDate.AddMinutes(60);

    services.HttpHeaders.Add("X-AnchorMailbox","impersonateduser@exchserver.com");

    appointment.Subject = "from Test";
    appointment.Body = "Test";
    appointment.Start = startDate;
    appointment.End = appointment.Start.AddMinutes(30);
    appointment.ReminderDueBy = appointment.Start.AddHours(1);
    appointment.Sensitivity = Sensitivity.Private;
    ImpersonatedUserId = new ImpersonatedUserId(ConnectingIdType.SmtpAddress, "impersonateduser@exchserver.com");

    appointment.Save(SalesCalendarId, SendInvitationsMode.SendToNone);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use impersonated user to obtain ‘owner’ permissions.

Please include the code below  before `services.Credentials = new WebCredentials("master@exchserver.com", "MasterPwd")`

```
services.PreAuthenticate = true;
```

you need to make sure that we have required permissions for EWS Impersonation as per the article mentioned below:

[Configuring Exchange Impersonation in Exchange 2010](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-2010/bb204095(v=exchg.140))

[Using Exchange Impersonation in Exchange 2010](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-2010/bb204088(v=exchg.140))

You could reference the following link:

[Get all calendar events for a specific user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34069443/get-all-calendar-events-for-a-specific-user)

Comment: That didn't help. Anyway, thanks for your reply, Alina. And I already tried Delegate technique. Neither that worked. Perhaps there is no way to provide that logic: trying to differentiate user rights for shared calendar on appointments level. Everybody can observe all appointments, but can see details of only it's own appointments. Anybody can answer this question? May be Glen Scales?

Comment: You could reference this link  :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-access-a-calendar-as-a-delegate-by-using-ews-in-exchange. when you save the item, the Save method call must identify the mailbox owner's Calendar folder.

Comment: Thanks Alina. I tried that before, and I did it again. That didn't help. Maximum what I can reach - is to see that last modified name is impersonateduser@exchserver.com, but organizer (and .Private property is under him, as well) is master@exchserver.com. Whenever you work with email sending with any technique: impersonating or delegate, that works fine, but I can't reach the goal to place an appointment by impersonated user with private property.

Comment: You could reference this link(the article's answer) : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30594319/office365-api-admin-accessing-another-users-rooms-calendar-events.